# Arguments.callee replacement for detecting incorrect constructor uses

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments, prototype

I'm reading John Resig's excellent book "Secrets of the Javascript Ninja"( http://www.manning.com/resig/ )

In it he has a very nice method for catching constructors being called as functions -

```
function User(first, last)
    if((!this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        return new User(first, last);
    }
}
```

Now I know it's possible to just manually put the name of the class in there for each function but if I want to be clever and extend all of my constructors from a "BaseConstructor" by setting a boolean then how would I accomplish this without arguments.callee?

Something like (untested )

```
function BaseConstructor() {}
BaseConstructor.prototype.calledCorrectly = (function () { 
    return !this.instanceof arguments.callee;
})();
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this without losing the constructor's name, or evaling.